# how to save/load game state in UIKit based Game using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am developing a game in Swift using UIKit. I want to save/load the changes each time the game is closed and opened. Data need to be saved/loaded are classes containing String and Int's.

Sample class:

```
class UserData {
     var username: String = String()
     var gamepoints: String = String() 
     var items: [UserItem] = [] 
}

class UserItem {
     var name: String = String()
     var quantity: Int = 0
     var price: Int = 0
}
```

I only need to save classes similar to ones above. What method should I use? How do I retrieve the updated values of the instance of the UserData class when the game is closed and opened again? Is there a method which I can save this class values to somewhere and initialize them after restarting the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.  You're going to want to look into `NSCoding` and `NSKeyedArchiver`.  Basically you will need to do the following steps:

1. Have your `UserData` and `UserItem` classes implement the `NSCoding` protocol.
2. Write them to disk when you need to using `NSKeyedArchiver`
3. Read them from disk when you need to using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`

Checkout this article about it: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

However you have many other options for storing user data - you could also store user data using `NSUserDefaults`, CoreData, SQLite, etc.  Your question is really quite broad, and without knowing the specifics of your game: how often it needs to read/output this data, how much of it there is, what data structures you're using to collect it... it's hard to give you a definite right answer.